# Does the SE network have any special occasions for this day?

Tags: discussion

I just realized that today, September 28th is celebrated as the [*Ask a Stupid Question Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask_a_Stupid_Question_Day). Although I don't have high hopes, but I wanted to know whether this day is recognized/celebrated on StackExchange sites.

P.S. Does my question fall in this category?

Comment: Here comes the flood of downvotes. So help me God

Comment: Meh, downvotes aren't a big deal. What do they hurt?

Comment: @Rubisco Some people take it personal and some don't. Generally for someone who is asking his first question this doesn't look like a nice reaction. Anyway, point taken

Comment: It's not a reaction, it's lack of a reaction. Here, or in any other meta, downvotes only show disagreement with the question's sentiment.

Comment: @Rubisco The problem is, I see no sentiment. Just a simple question

Comment: The downvotes could be saying something like "I don't want a stupid-question day" or anything like that. You should only take downvotes seriously when they're meant to send a strong message, and on a main site, not here. This is meta, and people vote for a billion reasons.

Comment: I downvoted this question because it's stupid.  HAPPY STUPID QUESTION DAY!!!!!

Comment: @Won't : If I ask a stupid question on the stupid question day, does it really deserve a dowvote? So what would be the point of celebrating such day?

Comment: ... ... .... ..... don't be stupid.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every day is "Ask a Stupid Question Day" here. Questions are, as a rule, stupid. If you knew the answer, you wouldn't need to ask the question.

[Jeff compares questions to the grains of sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) that exist in vast quantities, some small number of which make their way into oysters... And eventually become pearls of varying quality. Not every grain of sand becomes a pearl, and not every pearl is all that great... But our goal here is to provide a comfortable place for the oysters so that the sand may have a purpose.

Of course, some do find beauty in questions themselves, taking joy in the endless thoughts they inspire apart from any answers that might satisfy them. [Here's a fun comic by Kostas Kiriakakis](http://kiriakakis.net/comics/mused/a-day-at-the-park):

[image]

If that's your bent, then don't even worry whether the questions you read are "stupid" or not; just enjoy them for what they are. Also, check out [Quora.com](https://www.quora.com/), which is just chock *full* of unanswerable questions and various folks' musings on them.

Comment: I feel this comic should become internet sensation, but then the author would be compelled to make a lot more for less quality and some people will start copying it etc.